# SBT gives error "You have JDK version 0" - Windows

Tags: scala, sbt

SBT gives error like "The java installation you have is not up to date
sbt requires at least version 1.6+, you have version 0" , even though I have JDK 1.8 installed.

If I give "java -version" in windows command prompt, it displays java 1.8.

How to make SBT to point this JDK?

Thanks,
Jeeva

Comment: `java -version` is a poor way to check your JDK version, it really only checks the JRE version but.  try `javac -version`

Comment: Maybe you should reset the Environment variables(path and classpath of sbt).

Comment: I prefer to use https://sdkman.io in this kind of situations. It's allow easily choose appropriate version